# How to create a background variable in App Inventor, so i can change the background image of a canvas using spinner

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm working on a simple app using **App Inventor**, visual block coding. I have a canvas and would like to be able to change the canvas background image from a spinner.

I have got the spinner but can't get the blocks to make the spinner work. So basically on spinner (background1, background2) and below it the background that changes depending on the option i choose from spinner. Tried looking it up but can't find anything.

Comment: Hi, can you post the code which you have already tried?

Answer (score 1):

set the `Canvas.BackgroundImage` in the `Spinner.AfterSelecting` event

[image]